# image is not displayed

Tags: python, pygame, filenames

All works but image is not displayed. Only black screen. Why? That's the code:

```
import pygame

window = pygame.display.set_mode((600, 600))
pygame.display.set_caption("ASSHOLE!")
screen = pygame.Surface((600, 600))
screen.fill((50,50,50))

class Sprite:
    def __init__(self, xpos, ypos, filename):
        self.x=xpos
        self.y=ypos
        self.bitmap=pygame.image.load(filename)
        self.bitmap.set_colorkey((0,0,0))
    def render(self):
        screen.blit(self.bitmap, (self.x,self.y))

laser = Sprite(0, 0, 'laser.png')

done = True
while done:
    for e in pygame.event.get():
        if e.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = False

screen.fill((50,50,50))

laser.render()
window.blit(screen, (0,0))

window.blit(screen, (0, 0))
pygame.display.flip()
```

Have no idea why is it that. First decided to learn a python.

Comment: was not clear enough

Comment: What was not clear enough?

Comment: You decided to learn python by asking someone else to do it for you? Your game title is apt.

Answer (score 0):

First you don't need these four lines:

```
screen = pygame.Surface((600, 600))
screen.fill((50,50,50))

... 

window.blit(screen, (0,0))

window.blit(screen, (0, 0))
```

And you should replace `screen.fill` with `window.fill`.

Then when you exit image will show up and then program will quit.
If you want for image to be shown  all the time you should put `screen.fill`, `laser.render` and `display.flip` in `while done` loop (but not in `for` loop)

You should add `pygame.time.wait(500)  # Or any other number` on the end of the file so you program doesn't quit immediately after you press exit button.

Comment: well, i threw out the lines as you said and i have same black screen and after quit i get message NameError: name 'screen' is not defined. So when I put screen.fill, laser.render and display.flip in while done, I have the same but window closes immediately. When I put pygame.Surface((600, 600)) there's no error but still black screen. I think the reason is something else.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in indents under the "while done" loop (doublicated lines "window.blit(screen, (0,0))" and "screen.fill((50,50,50))" are eliminated too but that was not grave mistake). Сorrect code:

```
import pygame

window = pygame.display.set_mode((600, 600))
pygame.display.set_caption("GAME")
screen = pygame.Surface((600, 600))

class Sprite:
    def __init__(self, xpos, ypos, filename):
        self.x=xpos
        self.y=ypos
        self.bitmap=pygame.image.load(filename)
        self.bitmap.set_colorkey((0,0,0))
    def render(self):
        screen.blit(self.bitmap, (self.x,self.y))

laser = Sprite(0, 0, 'laser.png')

done = True
while done:
    window.fill((50,50,50))
    for e in pygame.event.get():
        if e.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = False

    screen.fill((50,50,50))

    laser.render()
    window.blit(screen, (0,0))
    pygame.display.flip()
```